# Django - Template Tags

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I was using django-request. In which file we need to add the template tage code in the following link?

https://github.com/montylounge/django-request/blob/master/docs/templatetags.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it anywhere you like. It's for use in your own templates.

Answer (score 1):

for custom template tags,you should put it in a directory called templatetags in one of your apps ,,

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout